# I2C_SLAVE ioctl() failing with ENOTTY when used in JNI shared library

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am having a problem trying to use an I2C device in Android (Gingerbread) via JNI.

The problem is with the I2C_SLAVE ioctl call.  The following code works when compiled into a standalone program:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = -1;
    long rc;
    int addr = 0x22;


  if ( fd  < 0 ) {
      fd = open(radio_device, O_RDWR);
  }

#define I2C_SLAVE 0x0703

  if ( (rc = ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, addr)) < 0 ) {
      printf("RadioService: I2C slave addr failed! rc=%d errno= %d [%s]\n", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
  }
  else {
      printf("RadioService: I2C slave addr 0x%x set\n", addr);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Output when run (via `adb shell` ):

```
~ # testi2c
RadioService: I2C slave addr 0x22 set
```

However, the same code does not work as part of a JNI library:

```
void Java_biz_lectronix_android_radio_RadioService_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    long rc;
    int addr1 = 0x22;
    int addr2 = 0x18;

    if ( fd = open(radio_device, O_RDWR) < 0 ) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "RadioService", "I2C open failed! %s", strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "RadioService", "Opened fd");
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "RadioService", "I2C_SLAVE [0x%x], addr = %d (0x%x)", I2C_SLAVE, addr1, addr1 );

    if ( (rc = ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, addr1)) < 0 ) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "RadioService", "I2C slave addr1 failed! rc=%d errno= %d [%s]", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "RadioService", "I2C slave addr1 %d set", addr1);
    }

    if ( (rc = ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, addr2)) < 0 ) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "RadioService", "I2C slave addr2 failed! rc=%d errno= %d [%s]", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "RadioService", "I2C slave addr2 %d set", addr2);
    }

    return;
}
```

Logcat output:

```
01-02 03:03:10.904: E/RadioService(1602): I2C_SLAVE [0x703], addr = 34 (0x22)
01-02 03:03:10.904: E/RadioService(1602): I2C slave addr1 failed! rc=-1 errno= 25 [Not a typewriter]
01-02 03:03:10.904: E/RadioService(1602): I2C slave addr2 failed! rc=-1 errno= 25 [Not a typewriter]
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Not actually a problem with the I2C interface at all.  The issue is this line:

`if ( fd = open(radio_device, O_RDWR) < 0 ) {`

It should be this (note parentheses):

`if ( ( fd = open(radio_device, O_RDWR) ) < 0 ) {`

So, the I2C device is opened, but the comparison has higher priority than the assignment in C. The comparison fails, assigning 0 to fd - which is `stdin`. 
The `ioctl()` call then fails because I2C_SLAVE is an inappropriate ioctl command for the device.